# Notification permission when playing audio

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, notifications, audio-service

We are programming an application with Audio-Service plugin, and when we start playing an audio, the Android terminal asks for permission to receive notifications. Something that we don't need and we are not going to use, so it is indifferent to choose to accept or reject the permission. We would like it not to be shown, why is this, and is it possible to deactivate it in some way? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a foreground service?  Foreground services must have a notification.  If you're trying toplay music when not the foreground Activity, you're using a foreground Service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean, background native media control? Yes, I'm using it in Android. But, if I reject the permission, I have same result with it... The audio starts in foreground when I open the app, and it asks about notification permission.

Comment: if your use case is to play the audio even in the background then you need a foreground service with notification (this is mandatory) and notification permission declaration in the manifest is required

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it would not be necessary, I have tried several radio apps, and none of them ask for that permission. I don't know what difference there may be, because if I reject the permission, it works the same...